# How to use NumPy or Pandas to speed up operation

Tags: python, numpy

I have this code, where one object references 1 or more other objects which have scores associated with this.  The code is pretty slow in Python and I want to speed it up.  I assume this is a very common problem so I don't want to do it 'wrong'.  What is this problem called so I can google to find example efficient implementations?

```
import random
import secrets
import time
import math

# generate fake data

NUM_WORDS = 10000
NUM_SENTENCES = 10000
MAX_SENTENCE_LENGTH = 25

# these will be updated between each sampling
word_gain = [math.exp(4*random.random()) for i in range(NUM_WORDS)]
word_cost = [random.random() for i in range(NUM_WORDS)]
sentences = {}

# these will remain the same through each iteration
for i in range(NUM_SENTENCES):
    sentences[i] = [secrets.randbelow(NUM_WORDS) for i in range(3 + secrets.randbelow(MAX_SENTENCE_LENGTH - 3))]

start_time = time.time()

MAX_COST = 6.0

for j in range(50):

    best_index, best_value = -1, 0.0;
    for i in range(NUM_SENTENCES):
        cur_cost, cur_gain = 0.0, 0.0

        for j in sentences[i]:
            cur_cost += word_cost[j]
            cur_gain += word_gain[j]

        if cur_cost <= MAX_COST and cur_gain > best_value:
            best_index, best_value = i, cur_gain
    assert best_value > 0.0
    print(f"Best {best_index} {best_value}")

    # adjust scores based on find
    for j in sentences[best_index]:
        word_gain[j] = -0.01
        word_cost[j] /= 2

end_time = time.time()

print(f"Elapsed time {end_time - start_time}")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you need to convert `word_cost`, `word_gain` as well as `sentences[i]` (for all `i`) to Numpy array:

```py
# Use np.float32 if you do not care about having a high precision
# so it can be faster
word_cost_np = np.array(word_cost, dtype=np.float64)
word_gain_np = np.array(word_gain, dtype=np.float64)
sentences_np = {k: np.array(sentences[k], dtype=np.int32) for k in sentences}
```

Then you can *vectorize* the inner loop using:

```py
cur_cost = word_cost_np[sentences_np[i]].sum()
cur_gain = word_gain_np[sentences_np[i]].sum()
```

The second inner loop can also be vectorized using the same strategy:

```py
word_gain_np[sentences_np[best_index]] = -0.01
word_cost_np[sentences_np[best_index]] /= 2
```

Note that `sentences[best_index]` need **not to have duplicate items** since Numpy cannot vectorize such a thing. The bad new is that **there are actually duplicates**. This can be seen using:

```py
[np.sort(sentences_np[k]) for k in sentences_np if np.unique(sentences_np[k]).size != sentences_np[k].size]
```

Besides, note that the Numpy computation is slower (at least on my machine). This is because Numpy introduces a **significant overhead for small arrays** compare to the time to compute them.

Generally, the idea is to vectorize the outer loop so to operate on bigger arrays. Unfortunately, this is not possible here because of the **dictionary**. **Variable-sized arrays** are not supported by Numpy either. One can flatten the dict in a big array and encode the mapping but this is not a very common way to use Numpy.

In the end, I do not thing Numpy alone is suited for such a task. Numba can mostly solve the above issues. However, the dict is not easy to use in Numba codes. Besides, note that Pandas as the same issue with variable sized array (which is not surprising since Pandas is built on top of Numpy). Maybe [Awkward](https://github.com/scikit-hep/awkward) can solve this problem since it supports variable-sized arrays. Still, the duplicate are still an issue with Awkward. Combining Numba with Awkward is AFAIK possible, but not trivial for such a task.

Comment: Thanks for your detailed answer. Well I could make the data the same size by having a 'null word' value added that had weight and cost of zero.    My solution, to this point, has just been to do the calculation in Java.

Comment: It seems a good solution in this case to use another language like Java/C# or native languages like C++/Rust (this is unfortunately often the case when performance matters). Note that the PyPy interpreter can often speed up the execution of Python script without much effort. This is sometime great when you do not want to re-implement everything in a lower-level language. Especially for prototyping.

Comment: Or use Julia. It will be also very fast.